# How to strip a Linux system?

Tags: linux, libraries, runtime

I've been building my own Linux distribution, and I've stripped the binaries, etc. The system won't use GCC or development tools, as it will be a Chrome kiosk, so it would greatly help if I could strip down the system.

I was wondering, is there a way that I can delete all of the unused system files (like binaries, etc.) by watching what files/libraries are used during runtime? Maybe another method is preferred, but is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: It would probably be easier to do this by building up rather than stripping down.  Also, you may be interested in http://www.busybox.net/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the nickname `blender`?

Comment: Best place to ask is SuperUser.com

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, http://www.blender.org/. I am an avid user!

Comment: if you don't get answer here; try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

These are some things I would do:

- Build my own kernel with no loadable modules. (Build in all the required modules.)  Eliminates /lib/modules ..
- Review the init scripts and drop any programs that are not required.
- Use ldd on the programs that are run to identify the libaries that are required.
- Identify which commands can be replaced by busybox, and build a custom busybox to supply only those commands.
- Identify the programs required for support and add them in.

Consider looking at what is included in a distribution like OpenWRT to see what is required for a relatively base installation.  Remove what your don't need, and add what your do.  OpenWRT now has builder package which makes it easier to investigate the distribution.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll have to rethink the kernel, as my OS will have to run a bunch of different setups, but I'll definitely try `ldd` and BusyBox. Thanks!

Comment: It it needs to run on a bunch of setups you may want to build modules, but likely a limited set.  In that case consider locking the module set during startup.

Answer (score 2):

debootstrap is the tool you want. http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/426 . It's much better to build up rather than strip down.

Comment: Hmm, I'm building HLFS, so no Debian chroot jails for me! If I'm not mistaken, isn't this just a way to run a Debian install inside of a folder via `chroot`?

Answer (score 1):

start from something like [damn small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and build up from that. dsL image is at most 50 mb

Comment: Thanks, but I've already got a working HLFS system. All I need to do is remove all of the unused binaries and libraries, as they take up a lot of space (which I am trying to save)...

Answer (score 0):

For building your own Linux filesystem try [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). There are a lot of tutorials on the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Why bother? Is it security you're worried about, or space/memory? I would recommend: if in doubt, don't spend the time on it.

Comment: Simplicity => Security. If I have no servers, no applications, nothing that can be targeted, I'm pretty safe. Also, I am keeping the security libraries, so don't worry.

Comment: As for space, it feels bloated; 700MB for just Chrome and XOrg? That is the size of Ubuntu's disk, and *that* has a ton more packages.

Comment: That's likely compressed, though.

Comment: A basic install of Ubuntu is ~ 1 GB, and I've seen Linux systems that are under 10 MB. It is compressed pretty well, though.

Comment: Note LFS is a learning tool.  If you build everything as an individual, there's a chance of missing updates for [system software bugs](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68877/shellshock-dhcp-exploitation).  LFS doesn't provide security support (the book points you to general sources like US CERT) or even use packages for clean updates (e.g. if files are removed)?  ...ubuntu+apparmor isn't perfect but personally I've found tools around apt/dpkg quite useful for keeping a stripped-down system.  700MB doesn't sound wholly insane... I struggled to keep going on an EeePC 4GB.